# ValueTuple.Equals doesn't return true

Tags: c#, tuples

Given what is written in the documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple.equals?view=netframework-4.7.1 ) it seems that ValueTuple.Equals should always return **true**

Does it mean it will return true even if the tuples have different value in their fields?

I'm trying to test it but I cannot hit the `Console.Writeline` with this simple code:

```
if((1,2).Equals((2,1)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's true");
}
```

Is there any caveat I should be aware of?

I've tested with c# versions from 7.0 to 7.3

Comment: @RenéVogt I read in the msdn *Determines whether two ValueTuple instances are equal. **This method always returns true.***

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are reading documentation of non-generic `ValueTuple`. This one has no fields and represents an "empty" `ValueTuple`, so of course one empty tuple is always equal to another empty tuple.

In your example code you are using generic `ValueTuple<T1, T2>`, and this documentation article is not related to it. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2.equals?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_ValueTuple_2_Equals_System_ValueTuple__0__1__) is relevant `Equals` method documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from [source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ValueTuple/src/System/ValueTuple/ValueTuple.cs#L47) `ValueTuple.Equals` always returns `true` indeed, the same is written in docs. But `(1, 2)` has type `ValueType<int, int>` which has different `Equals` logic, see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ValueTuple/src/System/ValueTuple/ValueTuple.cs#L489).

Answer (score -2):

Tuple equality is memberwise, so `(1,2) == (1,2)` but `(1,2) != (2,1)`.